# PL/SQL trigger to update same table after update or insert

Tags: plsql, triggers, procedure

I need help for trigger or something like that. The problem is, I have several rows with same id and there is a column named status. Only one of these rows can be 'active' in same time. How change all others to 'inactive' after one row updated to 'active'.

Comment: Don't do it in a Trigger. Write a separate procedure to handle it.

Comment: could you please advise how do it? to write procedure and call it in trigger or call it in other way?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is to  make the process which does the insert to invoke a procedure which checks and updates all the rows, do not implement that logic in a Trigger,

Comment: You _can_ do it in a trigger, but you will a compound trigger, so you can remember which row you made active, and update all the other rows in the `after statement` part. But really, I agree with @SamirAmanov, although it is technically possible, you shouldn't do it. I've been building triggers like that for a decade, and it haunts me in my work and my dreams. It's so hard to test and maintain, and at some point it becomes hard to predicts what a simple update statement will do. Try to keep the use of triggers to a minimum, and keep business logic out of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you should do this in a stored procedure, which could look something like this:

```
create or replace procedure prc_ActivateThingy(p_Id number) as
begin
  update YourThingy t
  set t.Active = 'Y'
  where
    t.Id = p_Id;

  dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);

  if sql%rowcount = 0 then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'No thingy found with id ' || p_Id || '.');
  end if;

  update YourThingy t
  set t.Active = 'N'
  where t.Id <> p_Id;

  dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount);
end;
```

Doing it in a trigger will work as well, but eventually your application becomes hard to maintain if there is too much 'trigger magic'. It becomes harder to predict what fires when, and you can get into a tangled mess that makes it hard to implement new business logic, or technical refactorings.

So, for completeness, this is how to do it in a compound trigger, although again, it's advised to chose the option above.

```
create or replace trigger tiuc_YourThingy
for insert or update on YourThingy
compound trigger

  v_Id number;

  before each row is
  begin
    v_Id := null;
    if :new.Active = 'Y' then
      v_Id := :new.Id;
    end if;
  end before each row;

  after statement is
  begin
    if v_Id is not null then
      update YourThingy t
      set
        t.ACTIVE = 'N'
      where
        t.ID <> v_Id;
    end if;
  end after statement;

end;
```

Comment: I have tried both ways, it is helpful, thank you very much